# Unit for expressing energy eigenvalue in infinite potential well problem

Tags: eigenvalue

How are the energy eigenvalues expressed in a infinite potential well problem( Joules/eV)?

Comment: You can convert between J/eV/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physics should not depend on the system of units you choose to solve any problem, otherwise physics would in Europe will be different than physics in the US, which is stupid!

The answer to your question depends on the initial definition of units you use in your problem. You start with SI units, you end with Joules. You start with CGS, you end with ergs. You start with natural units, you end with eV.